# What is the appropriate way of calling suspending functions inside a suspendCoroutine block?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, suspend

I need to call a suspending function inside a `suspendCoroutine` block, before I call `continuation.resume()`.
What is the appropriate way of doing that?

```kotlin
private suspend fun someFunction() = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    //...
    val myResult = mySuspendingFunction() //<--- The IDE says "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body"
    cont.resume(myResult)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to wrap it around the `suspendCoroutine?`

Comment: `suspendCoroutine` is a low level wrapper that you really should only use to wrap non-coroutine asynchronous APIs. There's no reason you should need to call a suspend function from it.

Comment: The `suspendCoroutine` call wraps a callback-based api call. The `mySuspendingFunction` call is inside one of the callbacks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't call a `suspend` function in [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html) block, because it accepts non suspend block as parameter:

```
suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutine(
    crossinline block: (Continuation<T>) -> Unit
): T
```

'suspendCoroutine' mainly used when we have some legacy code with callbacks, e.g.:

```
suspend fun getUser(id: String): User = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
      Api.getUser(id) { user ->
          continuation.resume(user)
      }
}
```

If function `someFunction()` doesn't call Api with callbacks then you should reconsider your approach getting rid of 'suspendCoroutine':

```
private suspend fun someFunction() {
    // ...
    val myResult = mySuspendingFunction()
    // ...
}
```

If you still want to use `suspendCoroutine` move call of `mySuspendingFunction` out of `suspendCoroutine` block:

```
private suspend fun someFunction(): String {
    val myResult = mySuspendingFunction()

    return suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        //...
        cont.resume(myResult)
    }
}

suspend fun mySuspendingFunction(): String {
    delay(1000) // simulate request
    return "result"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the `suspendCoroutine` call is wrapping a callback-based api call. The call to `mySuspendingFunction` is inside one of the callbacks.
I imagine calling `CoroutineScope().launch{}` inside `suspendCoroutine` would be bad, right?

Comment: I guess it would be not a good idea. Why don't you call `mySuspendingFunction` before or after `someFunction`?

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. And I got a very good reason why I cannot reorder the executions. I want to build a suspend function for Kafka's Producer.send(data, callback) call. This all looked nice and worked - kind of. It turns out, the send method Kafka provides is both *async* and *blocking* at the same time. Awkward design! So I had the idea to call it using runInterruptible { producer.send(data, callback) } - but I can ONLY to this *in* the suspendCancellableCoroutine because to build the callback, I do need the continuation. Cannot do it before... :-( This is such a bad situation...

Answer (score 3):

It's best to avoid this and call the suspending function before `suspendCoroutine`, as others have answered. That is possible for the specific case in question.

However, that is not possible if you need the continuation.

(The following is for those, who found this question for the this reason, as @Zordid and I have. `chan.send` is an example of this.)

In which case, the following is a possible, but **error prone** way to do it, that I do *not* recommend:

```kotlin
suspend fun cont1() {
    //btw. for correct implementation, this should most likely be at least suspendCancellableCoroutine
    suspendCoroutine<Unit> { uCont ->
        val x = suspend { chan.send(foo(uCont)) }
        x.startCoroutine(Continuation(uCont.context) {
            if (it.isFailure)
                uCont.resumeWith(it)
            // else resumed by whatever reads from chan
        })
    }
}
```

(I think the error handling alone illustrates why it's not a great option, despite other problems.)

**A better, safer and cheaper way is to use `CompletableDeferred` if you can.**

If you *must* pass in a Continuation, it's still safer and probably cheaper to do:

```kotlin
suspend fun cont2() {
    val rslt = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()
    chan.send(foo(Continuation(currentCoroutineContext()) {
        rslt.completeWith(it)
    }))
    rslt.await()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used it like this: `CompletableDeferred<...>().apply { (...) completeWith(result) }.await()`