# How do I call a suspend function from a callback?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a suspendable (`updateData`) function which takes another suspend function as an argument (`transform`). In my `updateData` function I'm making a call to an asynchronous API and I need to pass the result to the `transform` suspend function.
My current problem is that calling the `transform` function shows the message "suspension functions can be called only within coroutine context".

Here's what the code looks like:

```
override suspend fun updateData(transform: suspend (prefs: Preferences) -> Preferences): Preferences {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        realtimeDatabase.runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {
            override fun doTransaction(currentData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
                val prefs: Preferences = currentData.toPreferences()

                // I need to call the transform() function here
                
                // transform(prefs)
                // This call shows the error "suspension functions can be called only within coroutine context"
                
                return Transaction.success(currentData)
            }

            override fun onComplete(
                error: DatabaseError?,
                committed: Boolean,
                currentData: DataSnapshot?
            ) {
                if (error != null) {
                    continuation.resumeWithException(error)
                } else {
                    continuation.resume(currentData.toPreferences())
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62670767/5861618), but it doesn't really solve my problem because I can't call the `transform` function outside of `doTransaction` (I need `currentData`).

Also, I can't make `transform` a normal "non-suspend" function because I'm overriding that function from another class.

My question is: How can I apply the `transform` suspend function to `currentData`?

Comment: Non-suspendable functions can't wait in any other wait than by blocking. So if you can't anyhow redesign your code to perform this transformation outside of the callback (so before/after it), then I think the only possible way is by using `runBlocking()`.

Comment: @broot Thanks, I'll consider using `runBlocking()`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly what your API is here, but maybe you can break this function up to do your transformation after the `suspendCoroutine` block so its being called inside the coroutine instead of in the API callback.

```
override suspend fun updateData(transform: suspend (prefs: Preferences) -> Preferences): Preferences {
    val retrievedPrefs = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        realtimeDatabase.runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {
            override fun doTransaction(currentData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
                return Transaction.success(currentData)
            }

            override fun onComplete(
                error: DatabaseError?,
                committed: Boolean,
                currentData: DataSnapshot?
            ) {
                if (error != null) {
                    continuation.resumeWithException(error)
                } else {
                    continuation.resume(currentData.toPreferences())
                }
            }
        })
    }
    return transform(retrievedPrefs)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I can't do it after because the `doTransaction` method should write the transformed values to the database before returning Transaction success.

Comment: What database library is this? There may be at least a way to avoid having this `doTransaction` function being called on the main thread, because otherwise `runBlocking` presents a problem.